# Train Tensorflow on Google Cloud ML

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, google-cloud-ml

I have a model that I am trying to train on my local machine, but it needs more RAM than I have on my computer.

Because of this, I wish to train this model on Google Cloud ML.

This model that I am trying to train uses Reinforcement Learning and takes some actions and receives rewards from an environment developed in Python that takes as input a CSV file.

How can I export these to be trained on Google Cloud ML?

Comment: If you use a ML lib without GCS support, then you need to copy your files to the VM using gsutil cli or TensorFlow IO wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Can these rewards files be stored in Google cloud storage? Tensorflow reads such files natively is you use tf.file